# How to get VSCode Gutters to show diff from upstream

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using VsCode and the gutter features (the blue, red, and green highlighted sections on the side) which show file modifications are extremely useful. However, after a commit, those gutters go away.

I would still like to see the gutter modifications compared to what's on origin/master. I know that using the gitlens extension you can use the "open changes with" command and select a branch to compare with. But that opens a new dialog with the two files side by side. What I'm looking for is a way to keep the gutters to show all my changes. That way the areas which I've changed are visible at a glance.

Comment: +1, InteliJ's Git Scope plugin does this and it's such a huge win https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope

Comment: vim-gitgutter has this too and it's super useful. https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to accomplish the same exact thing. I would sometimes avoid committing just so the vscode gutter line change indicators would remain intact. I've also searched for plugins that will accomplish this but I haven't found any. As jtprince has posted, the only workaround I have found is to use `git reset HEAD~1` where the number "1" is the number of commits before the current HEAD position you want to compare to. The git reset command without any options is really "git reset --mixed" so that means the "Master" reference will be moved back however many commits you specify, and then due to the default "--mixed" option, the index tree will also be updated to that commit which is what will allow vscode to show those gutter line change indicators we want referring back to the commit we want. Your working tree will remain untouched which allows this workaround to work without losing any data.
The one inconvenience with this workaround is that *you must reset the "Master" reference back to its initial position BEFORE you make another commit or you will lose the history of commits in between.*  You won’t lose any data changes but its sort of like a rebase, where any commits will be condensed into a single new commit.

So to recap, just run:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

*(where the number "1" is the number of commits before the current HEAD you want to compare to)*

**And then when you are ready to commit, you must first execute:**

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

which will move the HEAD pointer back to its previous position. And then you can make your new commit.

Just to explain the meaning of this command, then "1" in `git reset HEAD@{1}`means what the HEAD pointed to 1 change ago, and you can find this information using `git reflog`

An excellent explanation on how `git reset` works is located here on the Git website: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

Comment: I like the idea of (ab)using the flexibility of git to fill the functionality gap in the editor, thank you. However - maybe it'd be safer to create and checkout a new auxiliar branch first, and then do the `git reset ...`? That way, the "real" branch stays untouched and safe; later we can just checkout again the real branch, commit to it, etc. And the aux branch can just be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

It is not perfect (I'd like it to add gutter diffs and fix the jump to changes functionality) but this extension provides a pretty good solution:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letmaik.git-tree-compare

[image: image of git tree in action]

Comment: Gutter diff would make this the perfect solution to this problem, hope you can add this at some point. Still very good extension, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I accomplish this same workflow by doing a git reset to `origin/master`, and then resetting back to the previous commit before I make any other commits.

For example, if I am on a branch which is some commits ahead of `origin/master`, and want VSCode to show differences since `origin/master`, I would do:

```
git reset origin/master
```

This does not modify the content of any files, but it does move HEAD so that VSCode and other editors show the differences between `origin/master` and the current branch. Be careful not to make any git checkouts or commits while in this state, or you will have to use reflog to get back to the commits ahead of `origin/master`.

Then to return to the state with all of the commits ahead of master, do:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

This will move HEAD back to where it was before the first reset, and all of the file changes you have made since then will remain intact. At this point, `git diff` and VSCode will show the changes you have made since your last commit. You can make a commit in this state and it will contain only the changes you have made since that previous commit (i.e. not all of them since `origin/master`).